# Cypress installation on a 32-bit server

Tags: javascript, npm, cypress, npm-install, 32bit-64bit

For some reason, I have to install Cypress (version: 7.2.0) on a 32-bit machine. I notice that only 64-bit is supported on Linux:

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/installing-cypress#System-requirements

But, a 32-bit release is available for Windows. So I guess it is possible to somehow build Cypress (version: 7.2.0) for 32-bit Linux. I just need some help to point me in the right direction to build and install Cypress (version: 7.2.0) on a 32-bit Linux server.

Thanks!